Is there a way to vectorise this logic in python?
I'm working on a financial simulation problem and I have a very simple piece of code which leverages a for loop to get a result.
I think it should be possible to vectorise this, but I also think that it might need multiple vector operations and some clever math to achieve vectorisation and all the solutions I tried failed to produce the expected results.
# for size: 10000000 3.8 seconds
import numpy as np
negative_threshold = -50
positive_threshold = 30

LOWER_BOND_RISK = -10000
UPPER_BOUND_RISK = 200000
SIZE_TO_RUN = 100000

no_hedges_flows_vector = np.random.randint(LOWER_BOND_RISK, UPPER_BOUND_RISK, size=SIZE_TO_RUN)
no_hedges_flows_vector

hedges_vector = np.zeros(len(no_hedges_flows_vector))

position = 0 # We start at 0 risk
for i,no_hedges_flow in enumerate(no_hedges_flows_vector):
    previous_position=position
    position += no_hedges_flow
    if ((position < negative_threshold)| (position > positive_threshold)): # we hedge
        hedges_vector[i] = -position 
        position = 0


hedged_positions_vector = hedges_vector.cumsum()  + no_hedges_flows_vector.cumsum()

assert np.all(hedged_positions_vector >= negative_threshold)
assert np.all(hedged_positions_vector <= positive_threshold)
assert np.all(hedges_vector >= -(UPPER_BOUND_RISK + positive_threshold))
assert np.all(hedges_vector <= -(LOWER_BOND_RISK + negative_threshold))

Essentially what the above code does is that:
Given a vector of risk changes in a currency, on each iteration it decides to hedge or not, where "hedge" just means adding a equal and opposite risk change to the "hedges_vector" and decreasing the risk by "hedge" amount. The decision to hedge depends if the current position (as the sum of all risk changes (including hedges) until now is within the accepted boundaries or not
I tried a few cases myself but all failed assertions and in retrospect were logically wrongly structured. I tried also my luck with ChatGPT but also that did not help at all (was failing assertions and trying to change those instead of the code even when asked not to do it. https://chat.openai.com/share/248403f1-12a6-45d1-ab1d-904a0344490b)
The above code is not super slow, but a vectorised version will be needed as this is performance critical

In this case I'd use numba to speed up the processing:
import numba


@numba.njit
def func_numba(no_hedges_flows_vector):
    hedges_vector = np.zeros_like(no_hedges_flows_vector)

    position = 0  # We start at 0 risk
    for i, no_hedges_flow in enumerate(no_hedges_flows_vector):
        position += no_hedges_flow
        if (position < negative_threshold) | (
            position > positive_threshold
        ):  # we hedge
            hedges_vector[i] = -position
            position = 0

    hedged_positions_vector = hedges_vector.cumsum() + no_hedges_flows_vector.cumsum()
    return hedged_positions_vector


Benchmark:
from timeit import timeit

import numba
import numpy as np

negative_threshold = -50
positive_threshold = 30

LOWER_BOND_RISK = -10000
UPPER_BOUND_RISK = 200000
SIZE_TO_RUN = 10000000

np.random.seed(0)

no_hedges_flows_vector = np.random.randint(
    LOWER_BOND_RISK, UPPER_BOUND_RISK, size=SIZE_TO_RUN
)


def func_normal(no_hedges_flows_vector):
    hedges_vector = np.zeros(len(no_hedges_flows_vector))

    position = 0  # We start at 0 risk
    for i, no_hedges_flow in enumerate(no_hedges_flows_vector):
        position += no_hedges_flow
        if (position < negative_threshold) | (
            position > positive_threshold
        ):  # we hedge
            hedges_vector[i] = -position
            position = 0

    hedged_positions_vector = hedges_vector.cumsum() + no_hedges_flows_vector.cumsum()
    return hedged_positions_vector



@numba.njit
def func_numba(no_hedges_flows_vector):
    hedges_vector = np.zeros_like(no_hedges_flows_vector)

    position = 0  # We start at 0 risk
    for i, no_hedges_flow in enumerate(no_hedges_flows_vector):
        position += no_hedges_flow
        if (position < negative_threshold) | (
            position > positive_threshold
        ):  # we hedge
            hedges_vector[i] = -position
            position = 0

    hedged_positions_vector = hedges_vector.cumsum() + no_hedges_flows_vector.cumsum()
    return hedged_positions_vector


r1 = func_normal(no_hedges_flows_vector)
r2 = func_numba(no_hedges_flows_vector)

assert np.allclose(r1, r2)

assert np.all(r1 >= negative_threshold)
assert np.all(r2 <= positive_threshold)

t1 = timeit("func_normal(no_hedges_flows_vector)", number=1, globals=globals())
t2 = timeit("func_numba(no_hedges_flows_vector)", number=1, globals=globals())

print(t1)
print(t2)

Prints on my machine (AMD 5700x):
2.648123851045966
0.1116715909447521

So speed-up of ~23x

I'm not at my computer right now, but can't you do func_numba = numba.njit(func_normal) rather than copying the function again with the name change and decorator?

@jared Yes, you can write func_numba = numba.njit(func_normal) and it will work the same. I just want to be more explicit in the code.
